# Select text from combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a simple question:

I have a combobox in WPF, but i want users to be able to copy the text from it to the clipboard. So select the displayed text of the selected item and right-click copy or ctrl+c. Just like default windows behaviour.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="ProductName"
    IsEditable="True"                               
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStroomProduct}">
</ComboBox>
```

How can i do that without using code behind or putting a lame button next to it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do something special to swallow mouse click events and keyboard input events the text box inside the editable combo box will support a context menu with clipboard commands including accelerator shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So basically simply putting a `<ComboBox>` on a WPF window having `IsEditable="True"` does not exhibit the behavior you describe.