# How to enable ctrl+c shortcut in ComboBox (WindowsForm)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am developing an app in C# with Visual Studio using Windows Forms

I have a *ComboxBox* and I would like to enable the **Ctrl+C** shortcut.
Right now it does not work (the selected text is simply not copied to the clipboard)
With a *TextBox* I simply need to set ShortcutEnabled to true, but this property does not seem to exist for *ComboBox*
Appearently it is what the guy in [there](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9354742b-4dcb-4b75-a5fd-7ed0bc900cd2/how-do-i-enable-ctrl-v-and-ctrl-c-for-a-combobox?forum=csharpgeneral) tries to do but I don't undersand what he means.
MSDN does not elaborate much on how to do..

Shall I try to manually catch the shortcut in the 

`private void mycomboboxname_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)`

method ?
That seems to me like an overkill... I looked  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259245/select-text-from-combobox) but did not understood it well (I can't find the *IsEditable* property when designing the form)
Any ideas welcome...

Comment: It depends on the DropDownStyle property.  If it is DropDown then the combobox is already a TextBox control under the hood and Ctrl+C works by default.  But if it is a DropDownList then it doesn't, nor would the user think Ctrl+C does anything useful.  But you can certainly add it with KeyDown.

Comment: My DropDownStyle is already DropDown. I tried Simple but still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant answer is right.
The key presses were simply intercepted (and prevented somewhere else in my code).